# How to use JButton to go to another java file (another class)

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I have two java classes: Menu and PMotion. The Menu class contains a JButton as shown below. When this JButton is pressed, I want it to go to PMotion.java

How to achieve this?

Menu.java

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
// Here I need to write the code which takes the user to PMotion.java
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample on how to open a new JFrame using a JButton.

```
    JButton show = new JButton("show Form2");
    show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            PMotion pMotion = new PMotion();
            pMotion.setVisibile(true); // Show pMotion form
            Form1.this.setVisible(false); // Hide current form where Form1 is your current JFrame class
        }

    });
```

Comment: Hi! I'm getting errors in //Show pMotion form and //Hide current form.
The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type PMotion
and The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}

Comment: @javaprogrammer it should work if `PMotion` extends `JFrame`. If PMotion does not extend anything then it will not work. What kind of class is `PMotion`?

Comment: Hi Ephraim. I made PMotion extend JFrame. The only error now is in the line this.setVisible(false); 
The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type new ActionListener(){}

Comment: I assumed that the current java class also extends jframe. You can remove that line if it does not.

Comment: The current class also extends JFrame

Comment: @javaprogrammer updated the answer. I just added that line in-case you want to hide the current JFrame upon showing PMotion.

Comment: Now it's hiding the current JFrame, but instead of showing PMotion, it just opens a blank JFrame, haha!